# How to partition Ubuntu 13.10 in order to install windows 7? NO DUAL BOOT

Tags: partitioning, windows

I have been using ubuntu for almost a year now, and it is just not working out for me. I would like to switch back to windows. I have both a Windows 7 installation dvd, and a windows xp installation disc, as well as my old ubuntu 12.10 boot dvd before I updated.

I am currently NOT running a dual boot system, it is solely Ubuntu, I erased windows when I switched.

I have no idea how to parition my drive to NTFS, and I would like to be able to do it in under 5 hours.

I know I may be a bit vague, but does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Won't the windows install disk automatically overwrite the Ubuntu install with its own partitioning? Or are you asking this as you want to transfer files to the new windows install from Ubuntu before getting rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

The Windows disks should be able to do it, just do a custom install and select to wipe the disk, a partitioner should be included.

Comment: It gives me an error when I attempt to do that.

"Windows cannot be installed to this hard disk space. Windows must be installed to a parition formatted to NTFS.

Comment: If you are installing windows 7, click Custom(Advanced), and then select your disk and click Drive Options(Advanced). Click Format, and OK. Then you should be able to use the disk and continue with the installation.

Comment: "Format is grayed out"